# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

am trying to read file from S3 in spark-shell. But am getting the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException
```

I have copied aws-java-sdk-1.11.106.jar, hadoop-aws-2.8.0.jar into jars folder. Could you please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The `com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException` is in `aws-java-sdk-core-*.jar` library. BTW, be careful as it would be your first problem. Normally, the code is looking for  `AmazonClientException` whenever there is an error.